# BlogEngine config fail with sub domain?

Tags: blogengine.net

I use godaddy hosting with IIS7, there is a blogengine in the root, I create a new subdomain named: http://leech.code2code.info (PHP code).

I din't work. I did the same like instruction http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/32808

But the problem still occur.

Please advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reread the error message. This doesn't seem like you're having some config error in your code. Your webserver is missing an assembly it needs to execute the code. The server is missing the component "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" or it couldn't load the correct version.

Check the file `D:\hosting\6918570\html\web.config` on line 74 for this reference. It might work removing the dependency (backup the file first), but that really depends on the code used.

The linked thread is talking about a different issue, just resulting in a similar error message.

Comment: When i remove the code line 74 in web.config, i got another error: "Could not load file or assembly 'BlogEngine.Core' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. "

I use blogengine v2.5.0.5 in the root domain.

Thanks

Comment: So you actually need the dependency and it's somehow missing on the server (or a different version). You might be able to just use your local assembly copy and place it next to your other project files, but wouldn't count on this.

Comment: I have followed the instruction in http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/32808, but it didn't work

Comment: As mentioned, you just might have to copy the correct DLLs to the bin directory. If you're compiling from source, select the dependency "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" and set the property "Local Copy" to true. This should add the assembly to the files uploaded which might solve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions on BIN deploying by Scott Hanselman helped me.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx